# Laravel wherehas can'it load the right foreign key

Tags: php, sql, laravel, filter

I have relations between User and Entry Models one to many 
but I didn't used user_id like a foreign key, I used supplier_id 
so when i tried to filter data with where has I have the following sql error : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entries.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from` users`where`role`= supplier and`users`.`company_id`= 1 and exists (select * from`entries`where`users`.`id `= **`entries`.`user_id`** and` entry_date `between 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-31))`

I think that the query must be like ...........`entries`.`supplier_id`....... not user_id because i set the relation with specific foreign key : 
Entry.php

```
public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'supplier_id');
    }
```

there is any way to set foreign key in whereHas clause ?

the code of filter :

```
 public function scopeEntriesBetween($query, $start, $end)
    {
        $query->whereHas('entries', function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query->whereBetween(
                'entry_date',
                [$start->format('Y-m-d'), $end->format('Y-m-d')]
            );
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you did for the relation from Entry to User, do the same for the relation from User to Entry

```
class User//..
{
    //..
    public function entries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Entry::class, 'supplier_id');
    }
    //..
}
```

Now you can use the relation `entries` in whereHas or directly with the right foreign key

Comment: this is cool ! i did this the first time : `return $this->hasMany(Entry::class);` just i forgot to add the foreign key.. thank you